# All routes besides home route are forbidden in laravel in centos

Tags: laravel, centos6

I have a problem on centos 6 with laravel.

Only home route works:

```
Route::get('/');
```

Everything besides this is on forbidden 403 error.

So it is not problem with home route and editing htaccess file but with something else and what is that I dont know...

Any help?

Comment: Could it be folder and files read, write, permission for the user? And who owns the files?